# IMobileServiceSyncTable.PullAsync - how to ensure query is securely scoped to a specific user?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

Unsure how `IMobileServiceSyncTable` security works - say I have a table, and it stores data for multiple users.

Following [this Azure App Services tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync/), it looks like I can query - from a mobile app - for pretty much any record, for any user, that I want.

**Client-side (e.g., Xamarin):**

```
await todoTable.PullAsync("todoItems" + userid, 
        syncTable.Where(u => u.UserId = userid));
```

Is there a way (server-side) to automatically scope records to the current authenticated user? Or is that done for you automatically if you decorate your table controllers with the `[Authorize]` attribute?

**Server-side:**

```
[Authorize]
public class TodoItemController : TableController<TodoItem>
{
    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        MyAppContext context = new MyAppContext();
        DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<TodoItem>(context, Request);
    }

    // GET tables/TodoItem
    public IQueryable<TodoItem> GetAllTodoItems()
    {
        return Query();
    }

    // GET tables/TodoItem/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
    public SingleResult<TodoItem> GetTodoItem(string id)
    {
        return Lookup(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this blog post (assuming ASP.NET): http://shellmonger.com/2016/05/09/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-18-asp-net-authentication/ - it adjusts the table controller to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Perfect, that was indeed exactly what I wanted! Thanks!